# There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [login] associated with context path [/jilmt]

Tags: java, struts2, jboss5.x, struts-action, action-mapping

I am getting this exception in `jboss 5.1.0`m but if I deploy it in `jboss 5.0.0` it works fine.

```
10:02:28,379 WARN  [ServletUrlRenderer] No configuration found for the specified action: 'login' in namespace: '/'. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.
10:02:28,406 WARN  [ServletUrlRenderer] No configuration found for the specified action: 'feedBack' in namespace: '/'. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.
10:02:28,489 WARN  [ServletUrlRenderer] No configuration found for the specified action: 'feedBack' in namespace: '/'. Form action defaulting to 'action' attribute's literal value.
10:02:45,644 WARN  [Dispatcher] Could not find action or result
There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [login] associated with context path [/eilmt]. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:185)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
```

struts.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts SYSTEM "struts2.3.dtd">

<struts>
<constant name="struts.multipart.saveDir" value="F:\fileU" />
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/.*FileUploadServlet.*,/.*SendFileData.*" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="global" />
    <!-- for understanding purpose only -->
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
```

Comment: Appearently, you have not created the `index` Action.

Comment: There's no action mapped, because there's no action configuration.